# Do an action while a button is pressed in RPi.GPIO using add_event_detect

Tags: pi-3

I have made a circuit in which a buzzer buzzes when a button is pressed. It works fine if I use a `while` loop and continuously detect button state. AFAIK, this is not an efficient way and I should use callbacks.

This works

mport RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

```
try:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        
        while True:
                if(GPIO.input(12) == GPIO.LOW):
                        GPIO.output(11,GPIO.HIGH)
                else:
                        GPIO.output(11,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(0.01)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I am not able to write equivalent code using `add_event_detect`

This code doesn't work

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def handle_button_press_event(button_pin):
        print('button pressed for pin ',button_pin)
        if(GPIO.input(12) == GPIO.LOW):
                GPIO.output(11,GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
                GPIO.output(11,GPIO.LOW)

try:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(12,GPIO.FALLING,callback=handle_button_press_event,bouncetime=5)
        while True:
                time.sleep(0.01)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

What is the way to use callbacks and do an operation when only for the time when the button is pressed. The operation should stop when the button is released.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the system to check for falling events (transition from high to low) when you set up the callback.

You need to check for rising and falling events.  Use `GPIO.BOTH` rather than `GPIO.FALLING`.